# Removing specific text from a box?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Is there a way to remove text from a box in google sheets? Here is a example:

```
Total: [=sum(stuff here)]
User 1   5 points
User 2   8 points
```

The `[5 points]` is one cell. If I just try to sum it up, it just gives me a 0. Is there a way for formula to ignore text and only read numbers in a cell? If you could help, That would be great! :)

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: @marikamitos I had a meeting. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula do the job

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(E2:E3,"\d{1,}"))))
```

- `REGEXTRACT` use regular expressions to extract text and works fine together with `VALUE` and `ARRAYFORMULA`
- `\d{1,}` is a regular expression that match any digit (0-9) following by any number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following formula

```
="Total: "&ArrayFormula(SUM(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B,"\d{1,}")*1)))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669)
- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)

Comment: By the way have you tested the accepted formula when empty cells are present?